# How to remove white space in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

How can I remove the white space that automatically typed together with the letter(s) in my autocompletetextview whenever I click my imagebutton(s)? and how can I make my imagebuttons' picture back to the first image (because here when the imagebutton is clicked the color of the image change and I want it to set back its original image after clicking a button) for example here using mycodes: from a to changea and back to a.
Heres my code:

```js
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
    if (arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
        Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
        generatedString=generatedString+("a"); 
        text.setText(generatedString);
        ((ImageButton) arg0).setImageResource(R.drawable.changea);
```

Answer (score 0):

a) To remove whitespace in a String use the method [**trim()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim())

b) to change the image located into your resources of an ImageView use the method [**setImageResource()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))
this is an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Heres the code to change from  an image "cat" to "dog".

```
Button btn;
ImageView img;
boolean click ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
            if(click){                      
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
                click = false;
            }else{
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
                click = true;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where should i put trim?